# Convolution product of arithmetic functions

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

> An arithmetic function is a real-valued function whose domain is the set of positive integers. Define the convolution product of two arithmetic functions $f$ and $g$ to be the arithmetic function $f \star g$, where $$(f \star g)(n) = \sum_{ij = n}f(i)g(j), \text{ and } f^{\star k} = f \star f \star \cdots \star f \text{ } (k \text{ times}).$$ We say that two arithmetic functions $f$ and $g$ are dependent if there exists a nontrivial polynomial of two variables $P(x,y) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}x^iy^j$ with real coefficients such that $$P(f,g) = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}f^{\star i} \star g^{\star j} = 0$$ and say that they are independent if they are not dependent. Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes and set $$f_1(n) = \begin{cases}1 \quad \text{if } n = p,\\0 \quad \text{otherwise}; \end{cases} \qquad \qquad f_2(n) = \begin{cases}1 \quad \text{if } n = q,\\0 \quad \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ Prove that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are independent.

My book says that $$f_{1}^{\star i}\star f_{2}^{\star j}(n) = \begin{cases}1 \,\, \text{if} \,\, n=p^{i}q^{j} \\ 0 \,\, \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ and the result follows from that, but how do they get that and how does the result follow from that?

Comment: In the definition of the convolution did you mean the sum $ \sum_{i+j = n}$ or the product $ \sum_{i\cdot j = n}$? The analogy from other fields suggests that it should be the sum...

Comment: @TZakrevskiy It should be $ij = n$. This is the Dirichlet convolution they are talking about.

Comment: Ok, then I'd start by calculating $f_1^{\star i}$ and $f_2^{\star j}$, and then I'd find $f_{1}^{\star i}\star f_{2}^{\star j}(n)$. Once there, suppose that these functions are independent, use the expressions you obtained to write explicitly $P(f_1,f_2)$ and obtain a contradiction

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I got that $$f_1^{\star i}(n) = \sum_{i_1j_1 = n}f_1(i_1)f_1^{\star (i-1)}(j_1) =  \sum_{i_1j_1 = n}f_1(i_1)\sum_{i_2j_2 = j_1}f_1(i_2)f_1^{\star(i-2)}(j_2) = \cdots = \sum_{i_1j_1 = n}f_1(i_1) \sum_{i_2j_2 = j_1}f_1(i_2)\cdots\sum_{i_{i-1}j_{i-1} = j_{i-2}}f_1(i_{i-1})$$ but don't see how that helps.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy How should I calculate $f_1^{\star i}(n)$ and $f_2^{\star j}(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write the convolution $$f_1\star f_1 (n) = \sum_{i\cdot j =n}f_1(i)f_1(j).$$

The function $f_1(i)\ne 0\iff i=p$, hence the only way to get a nonzero product inside the sum above is to put $i=j=p$. This implies that
$$f_1^{\star 2}(n)=\begin{cases}1,&n=p^2,\\0,&n\ne p^2.\end{cases}$$

By using the same technique, you will get that
$$f_1^{\star k}(n)=\begin{cases}1,&n=p^k,\\0,&n\ne p^k.\end{cases}$$

Can you now apply the same technique to $f_1^{\star k}\star f_2^{\star p}$?

Comment: What do we do once we get $$f_{1}^{\star i}\star f_{2}^{\star j}(n) = \begin{cases}1 &\text{if } n=p^{i}q^{j}, \\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}?$$

Comment: @user19405892 Write you function $P(f_1,f_2)(n) = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}f_{1}^{\star i}\star f_{2}^{\star j}(n)$, find its value for  all $n$. What do obtain?

Comment: $$P(f,g) = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}f^{\star i} \star g^{\star j} = a_{ij}$$ if $n = p^iq^j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @user19405892. That's correct, you are right. Now suppose that this polynomial is identically zero for all $n$, what can we conclude on $a_{ij}$?

Comment: Then the $a_{i,j}$ would all have to be $0$ and thus $P(x,y)$ would have to be the trivial polynomial.